# eclipse debug hadoop wordcount ,and Exception happened

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

when i run `hadoop wordcount` this exception happened

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.tracing.SpanReceiverHost.get(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/tracing/SpanReceiverHost;
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:634)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:520)
at com.chen.main.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:67)
```

i want to debug hadoop remotely and the input path is `hdfs://112.74.78.239:50040/user/root/input/words`
how should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

find / -name "*.jar" | xargs grep SpanReceiverHost.class

and find out all jars having this class reference apart from core hadoop libraries. There may be jars with same class but without latest method for which java throwing exception. Exclude jar from your class path  which has same class (older version) but without expected method.